# C++ const struct pointer not accessible

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constants

I have `const struct aiScene *scene;` declared in class.

In the function where I define `scene = importer.ReadFile(file, aiProcess_Triangulate);` , the scene struct is accessible. I can print out `scene->mNumMeshes` for example.

Problem is that scene is not correclty accessible from another functions. If I try to print out `scene->mNumMeshes` then it prints different numbers every time (memory addresses?).

How can I make scene accessible from every function in class?

Comment: Can you show us the function where you define `scene`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to be sure without knowing what's in `importer.ReadFile`, but a good guess would be that `importer.ReadFile` returns a pointer to a structure on the stack. After it returns, the structure will quickly get overwritten by other data -- in your first experiment you may just have gotten lucky to get at it before anything else reused that location.

Make sure that `ReadFile` returns a heap-allocated structure rather than a local one.

Comment: From Assimp library doc: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#174418ab41d5b8bc51a044895cb991e5

"The returned data is intended to be read-only, the importer object keeps ownership of the data and will destroy it upon destruction."

So, I had to move declaration of importer also into the header. Thank you!